# Is there a way to get Control+R style recursive command history searching in pry

Tags: ruby, pry

I've recently been playing around with pry.   Lot's of great stuff but I find myself missing `Control+R` from irb.  Pry has [the 'hist' command](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History) but I'd still like to be able to hit `Control+R` and start typing instead of having to do `hist --grep foo`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit the .editrc file in your home directory:

```
nano ~/.editrc
```

And add this line:

```
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

Source: [pry wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ/#wiki-readline)

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason. Neither in pry nor IRB and im losing my mind trying to figure out why

Comment: Why are you running it as root?